# About Mahakala, the abode of Sastha

Tags: reference-request, places

The 13rd chapter of Asura Khanda from Shankara Samhita mentiones that Sastha gives the duty to Ganesha for protect Sachi and went to his abode, Mahakala.

I want to know about this Mahakala. So my question is, Did any other scriptures mentioned this place?